# Make Some Columns Not Repeat Values with Google Sheets Query Formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula, unique

Supposing I have the following data on a table:

[image: Data]

And I want to return the result below:

[image: Desired Output]

Of course, query formula:=query(data!A:F,"SELECT A,B,C,F,D,E WHERE A=44910") won't achieve this b/c it will list all repeating values.

I am trying to list the results in column D and E (Location and Contact) only once instead of repeating them.

A sheet is shared [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U-qbD0s5V4ZdK2pY-ApzV0TGvz1_HfmpuuI0SSW4orY/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell A1:

```
=arrayformula({data!A1:C1,data!F1,data!D1:E1;filter({data!A2:C,data!F2:F,if(countifs(data!D2:D,data!D2:D,row(data!D2:D),"<="&row(data!D2:D))=1,data!D2:E,)},data!A2:A=44910)})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much all.  Work has kept me from returning to this - much appreciated and will comment back soon.

Answer (score 1):

Add formula to `G2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B1:B1501<>B2:B1502,{E2:E1502,F2:F1502},""))
```

then hide `E` and `F` columns

[image]

Comment: Really interesting approach.  I don't have the option of adding columns b/c the output exists to be pasted on to Gmail and shared as a list - and Gmail will not keep columns hidden as far as I can see.  However, I will be trying your approach by adding columns to the data set.  I have done so in the shared file and got it to work.  My challenge becomes adding an order by clause to the query.  This is really helpful though. I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add columns, apply conditional formatting in E2: F with the formula:

```
=$B1=$B2
```

with blank color

Comment: Brilliant.  Correct - I am not able to add columns - this works from a visual standpoint - will likely use this approach elsewhere - thanks for this strategy.